# (for me) ununderstandable bug in my code

Tags: java

I've been working on a project, which would need to much explaining to tell you what is it all about.

I wanted to make the program writes you a map (on the console), so I wrote Xs and Ys of all the buildings, which will be on the map, and the homeChars' chars mean, how would buildings look on the map.

First, I tried to make console writes down the first row, which should be AOOOS (each letter console writes in a different row, I'll change that in the future), but somehow, console throws out AOOOO instead.

```
public static void main(String []args){

    int homeXs[] = {1, 1, 3, 3};
    int homeYs[] = {1, 5, 3, 3};
    char homeChars[] = {'A', 'S', 'H', 'D'}; //ARMORY, STORE, HOME, DUNGEONS
    char homePlace[] = {'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'};

    for(int a = 0; a <= 4; a++){
        for(int b = 0; b <= 3; b++){
            if (homeYs[b] == 1) {
                if (homeXs[b] == a+1) {
                    homePlace[a] = homeChars[b];
                }
            }
        }

    }
    for(int c = 0; c <= 4; c++) {
        System.out.println(homePlace[c]);
    }

}
```

Q1: Why does the console write down O insted of the S, where is the bug and how to fix it? I've looked deep in the code but can't find it...

Q2: How to make so the AOOOS will be written in the same row? If I make:

System.out.println(homePlace[0]+ homePlace[1] + homePlace[2] + homePlace[3] + homePlace[4]);

the code would be ugly and it woudn't work, somehow it throws out a number...

Any help would be appreciated,

Enej Lah

Comment: There's no 5 in `homeXs`, so the iteration of the outer loop when `a` is 4 won't find any value to set `homePlace[a]` to.  So `homePlace[4]` has to stay as `"O"`.

Comment: And if you use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`, your stuff all gets printed on the same line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but no homeXs is a-dependent...

Comment: I have no idea what your last comment means, but I'm referring to the line `if (homeXs[b] == a+1) {` - it will never match anything if `a` is 4.

Comment: What about if b is 1 and if a is 4? Woudn't then S be accepted?

Comment: I suggest to use the debugger it will help you find the problem certainly.

Comment: @enejlah In your example, `homeXs[1]` is 1.  So you seem to be asking me whether 1 equals 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The only value for which you are in the second `if` is for `a = 0, b = 0`. So it's not possible to make your array `AOOOS`.
2. You can use `System.out.print()` in the loop.

Comment: 2nd question is solved, but woun't an S be created as an fifth O since I have an S for a=4 and b=1?

Comment: But `homeYs[1] != 1`

Comment: But now I tried to use the System.out.print() and it still throws me a number, 385 to be exact. Do I have to convert all these chars to the string and print the string, or is there an easier way?

Comment: What are you printing?

Answer (score 0):

To start with I'd recommend to refactor your code, for example

```
if (homeYs[b] == 1) {
    if (homeXs[b] == a+1) {
         homePlace[a] = homeChars[b];
    }
}
```

is equal to:

```
if (homeYs[b] == 1 && homeXs[b] == a+1) {
    homePlace[a] = homeChars[b];
}
```

which will lead to:

```
    for(int a = 0; a <= 4; a++){
        for(int b = 0; b <= 3; b++){
           if (homeYs[b] == 1 && homeXs[b] == a+1) {
                homePlace[a] = homeChars[b];
           }
        }
```

so it will make your intent a bit more clear. Therefore as you can see now why you are getting this results in your console.

Regarding to the printing, you might consider to use Java 8 stream API in following way:

```
Arrays.asList(homePlace)
         .stream()
      .forEach(System.out::print);
System.out.println()
```

---

For streaming API to work need to make sure your project configured with Java 1.8, for example with maven, following will do the thing:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <testTarget>1.8</testTarget>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: The code is better, but it sends me an error at the printing part. Do I have to import anything?

Comment: My bad :(, fixed.

Comment: just checked, compiles on Java 8, with no errors. Please make sure you're on Java 1.8

Comment: 1.8.0_144, I'll check if it is anthing wrong with the application I'm programming with (IntelliJ). Still thank you for your effort.

Comment: Check project language level, it should be: `8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.`

Comment: Ok, I'll check.

Comment: you can do it project settings :)

Comment: File -> Project Structure -> Project

Comment: yup, it is the 8th one. wait, where should i put the chars into so they get sent by a console?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question? You create a list out of array of characters, then you stream it and iterate over each character, while for each you are calling print method of static reference "System.out::print". You can replace it with Arrays.asList(homePlace)
         .stream()
      .forEach(c -> System.out.print(c)); which will be the same.

Comment: homePlace[0]+ homePlace[1] + homePlace[2] + homePlace[3] + homePlace[4] have to be put in System.out.println() as normal, right? I was just checking...

Comment: You know what...I'll try to convert these 5 chars in a single String. Thanks again.

Comment: > homePlace[0]+ homePlace[1] + homePlace[2] + homePlace[3] + homePlace[4] have to be put in System.out.println() as normal, right? I was just checking.

Sorry, but I'm not following you. The code as I've posted should work w/o any additional effort, you only need to make sure to run it on Java 8.